# AngularJS - Get previous route when firing controller

Tags: angularjs, routes

Angular's internals are baffling me again.

I need to determine the previous route when a specific view is loaded.

This is how I have done it

```
app.controller('TrashCtrl',function($scope,$rootScope){

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess',function(evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl) {

        var hashIndex = absOldUrl.indexOf('#');

        var oldRoute = absOldUrl.substr(hashIndex + 2);

        console.log(oldRoute);

    });

});
```

Unfortunately I have to call the view that corresponds with that controller once before the logic starts to work. The first time when the controller fires, nothing is logged. Furthermore, after this initial load, the application will log **every** routeChange, even if the loaded view is not working with `TrashCtrl`

I would like it like this:

- When the view `Trash` (whose controller is `TrashCtrl`) is loaded, I need the previous route or an empty string if this was the first one.
- It would be nice if this only fires when the actual `trash` route is called, not on every routechange.

How would one achieve this?

Edit:

Note that I am aware of the possibility of creating a custom service and writng each change to it. This is not what I want. I would like to fecth the data only when it is needed, e.g just when `Trash` is called.

Comment: Did you try using just `$scope` instead of `$rootScope`?

Comment: @callmekatootie
Yup. Same outcome

Comment: Since you mentioned something about _"fetching data"_, are you aware of the `resolve` property of `$routeProvider` route-objects ?

Comment: While I meant the URL by "data", this is actual a pretty good idea. I'll try, thank you

Comment: not able to understand your use-case. Can you create a plnker for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried what ever I could, but it seems there is no straightforward way to get access to the previous route's path inside of the **[`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)**'s `resolve` property.

Just for fun, I implemented a (ridiculously complex) solution with the following attributes:

- It detects the previous route only if the `/trash` view is loaded (not for every route).
- It doesn't have to know anything about the rest of the routes.
- No extra configuration is needed when adding additional routes (this adds implementation complexity, but simplifies maintainance).

---

#### In words

Here is how it works in "plain" words:

In the `resolve` object, it registers a listener for the next `$routeChangeSuccess` event.
Once the event is captured, it unregisters the listener.
Once the listener is unregistered, it resolves a promise with value of the previous route's path.
The object injected into the `trashCtrl` (from the `resolve` property) is a function, that returns the aforementioned promise.
The controller, receives that function, calls it to get the promise and waits for the promise to get resolved with the previous route's path.

Simple as pie !

<sub>**Note:**
For the sake of "simplicity" I haven't taken into account the posibility of an error leading to `$routeChangeError` (instead of `$routeChangeSuccess`). One should probably take that into account and deregister the listeners, but even if you don't, there will be no harm - the listener will leave on until the `$routeChangeSuccess` is fired once.</sub>

---

#### The code

The controller:

```
app.controller('trashCtrl', function ($scope, prevRoutePromiseGetter) {
    prevRoutePromiseGetter().then(function (prevRoute) {
        $scope.prevRoute = prevRoute || 'nowhere';
    });
});
```

The `resolve` object:

```
resolve: {
    prevRoutePromiseGetter: function ($q, $rootScope) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var dereg = $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', 
            function(evt, next, prev) {
                dereg();
                deferred.resolve((prev.originalPath || '').substr(1));
            }
        );
        return function () {
            return deferred.promise;
        };
    }
}
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/tKEs2/)**.

Comment: Answers like these are why I love this site. Big thanks for your efforts! I shoot for a simple service, yet it is nice to see that solution.

Comment: I just realized I never linked to the actual demo (just a docs page). Fixed :)

Comment: ExpertSystem, a seriously big time thank you for this!

Comment: Almost perfect, but I got `/company/edit/:id?` instead of getting the complete url... with that id.

Comment: @sylouuu: Hm...I think you can get hold on the route parameters inside the resolve function (using `$routeParams`).

Answer (score -1):

You need to be using the $routeChangeStart and not the location change.

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {

});
```

Comment: This won't trigger when calling the view for the first time, too